# How do I apply a filter to a prerecorded video?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, filter

I want to apply some filters (like a sepia tone, black and white, etc.) to a video file that is stored locally and save the filtered video in the application's documents directory.

I don't want to add a filter to live video. I have searched, but all of the questions I've seen are about applying filters to live video, not prerecorded ones.

Can someone please suggest where I can start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework. It can load locally stored movies, filter them using the same filters that you can apply to live video, and save the result to disk.

See the SimpleVideoFileFilter sample application that comes with the framework for an example of this in action.

Comment: But here one issue is that, for save the whole filtered (like sepia) video it takes time equal to total video duration for apply filter on whole prerecorded video.

Comment: @g212gs - Not necessarily. Video recording is an intensive operation, and depending on the size of the video and processor class of the device, re-encoding the video can either take significantly less than the run-time of the video or significantly longer. This will happen with no matter what process you use for applying a filter to video, and you'll be hard-pressed to find a faster way to filter the video than passing it through the GPU.

Comment: So, Is there any other way for make this process faster.. by any other alternative because if we want to apply filter on 10 min video it takes time up to 10 minutes.. it irritate users,
 i ask the same question in following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464454/gpuimagemovie-save-with-fielter-effect-with-increse-gpuimagemoviewriter-speed